# Active element is not getting focused

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to focus on the link on the blur event of a button using java script but it is not working.

on the press of the tab focus goes to the address bar.

**JavaScript**

```
    blur(closebutton: HTMLButtonElement, link: HTMLButtonElement,p) {


    console.log(closebutton);
    console.log(link);
    console.log(document.activeElement)

    link.focus();
    console.log("active element before closing popover")
    console.log(document.activeElement)
    console.log(document.hasFocus())
  }
```

**console output:**

```
<button class=​"close">​…​</button>​
<button class=​"popoverLink" container=​"body" html=​"true" placement=​"top-right bottom-right" popoverclass=​"custom-popover" triggers=​"manual" ng-reflect-auto-close=​"true" ng-reflect-ngb-popover=​"[object Object]​" ng-reflect-placement=​"top-right bottom-right" ng-reflect-triggers=​"manual" ng-reflect-container=​"body" ng-reflect-popover-class=​"custom-popover" aria-describedby=​"ngb-popover-1">​ DIV ​</button>​
<body class=​"mat-typography">​…​</body>​
active element before closing popover
<button class=​"popoverLink" container=​"body" html=​"true" placement=​"top-right bottom-right" popoverclass=​"custom-popover" triggers=​"manual" ng-reflect-auto-close=​"true" ng-reflect-ngb-popover=​"[object Object]​" ng-reflect-placement=​"top-right bottom-right" ng-reflect-triggers=​"manual" ng-reflect-container=​"body" ng-reflect-popover-class=​"custom-popover" aria-describedby=​"ngb-popover-1">​ DIV ​</button>​
true
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
          <ng-template #popContent>
            <span id="glossary">  {{element.description| glossary:glossaryDescription}}</span>
            <button class="close" (click)="p.close(); returnFocus(p)"  #closebutton  (focus)="true" (blur)="blur(closebutton,link,p)"><img src="assets/icons/close.svg"></button>

          </ng-template>
          <button class="popoverLink" [ngbPopover]="popContent"
                  triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover"
                  (click)="start = true; p.open(); returnFocus(p)" [autoClose]="true" placement="top-right bottom-right"
                  container="body"
                  html="true" popoverClass="custom-popover"   (shown)="openPopover(p);"   (keypress)=" keypress(p)" #link >

            {{split(element.description)[0]}}
          </button>
          /{{split(element.description)[1]}}
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: the tab key sets the focus to an other element. So what happens is: blur of button, then focus link, then focus where the "tab" wished to go (so ignore what you did before). You may have to do it with HTML (so tab will naturally go to your link), or use an harder code with something like "preventDefault" or "stopPropagation"...

Comment: have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: I can not use tabindex as each row in the table has link and which opens the popover. I have autofocused the popover close buttton and I want when I press tab focus come back to link which has opened the popover. see the screenshot